# Assigning Out parameters to Array elements with index c#

Tags: c#, arrays, parameters

I have a function wrapper, which is as defined below: Here I pass in a set of coefficients (*inputArr*), and a Tuple containing 2 double arrays.

The expected output is how many times the "*WminObjectivefunction*" shall be called and also to return the "*FuncValue*" which is basically "*WminObjectivefunction*" evaluated at "*inputArr*". Every time I call "*WrapFunction*" the array "*inputArr*" passed shall be different.

```
public void WrapFunction(out int ncalls, out double FuncValue, double[] inputArr, Tuple<List<double>, List<double>> arguments)
{
    int calls = 0;//Number_of_FunctionEvaluations
    // MASTER class instance  
    Master prismpy = new Master();
    calls += 1;//Number_of_FunctionEvaluations_Increment
    ncalls = calls;//Return_Number_of_FunctionEvaluations
    FuncValue = prismpy.WminObjectivefunction(inputArr, arguments.Item1, arguments.Item2);//Return_FunctionValuation
}
```

Question1: I want to store the *FuncValue* as elements in an Array *fsim*, How can I command the *WrapFunction* to store the value as an array element denoted by an index. The following is what I tried, and the error is : Cannot implicitly convert 'void' to 'double'

```
// FSIM: put array in array of arrays
double[] fsim = new double[5];
int fcall;
fsim[0] = WrapFunction(out fcall, out fsim[0], _x0, args);
```

Question2: Is it necessary to call WrapFunction with all out arguments every time ? Is there a way if I just want to get either one of those two outputs?

Comment: Isn't `ncalls` always going to be 1?  In which case the only useful information is the `FuncValue` and you could just return it instead of using an `out` parameter.

Comment: This is a huge code smell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, but I would guess like this:

```
public double WrapFunction(out int ncalls, out double FuncValue, double[] inputArr, Tuple<List<double>, List<double>> arguments)
{
    int calls = 0;//Number_of_FunctionEvaluations
    // MASTER class instance  
    Master prismpy = new Master();
    calls += 1;//Number_of_FunctionEvaluations_Increment
    ncalls = calls;//Return_Number_of_FunctionEvaluations
    FuncValue = prismpy.WminObjectivefunction(inputArr, arguments.Item1, arguments.Item2);//Return_FunctionValuation
    return FuncValue;
    // NOTE: the FuncValue parameter may be redundant -- RBarryYoung
}
```

Here's another version, that reflects some of the comments/discussion:

```
int calls = 0;//Number_of_FunctionEvaluations

public double WrapFunction(out int ncalls, double[] inputArr, Tuple<List<double>, List<double>> arguments)
{
    // MASTER class instance  
    Master prismpy = new Master();
    calls += 1;//Number_of_FunctionEvaluations_Increment
    ncalls = calls;//Return_Number_of_FunctionEvaluations
    return prismpy.WminObjectivefunction(inputArr, arguments.Item1, arguments.Item2);//Return_FunctionValuation
}
```

Comment: You can remove the `out double FuncValue` in this case.

Comment: @juharr True, but the OP's reqs seem vague and like they are part of some larger context, so I opted not to change the interface.  I will change it to set `FuncValue` also.

Comment: Ah yes, how can I validate how many times Wrap function is called ? In the present case, like @juharr said, its going to be 1 always.

Comment: @abhilashsukumari Then `calls` would need to be moved to a higher scope.  If you want number of calls on a specific instance then move it to the class level.  If you want it across all instances then you also need to make it static.

Comment: @abhilashsukumari OK, I will revert it and remove the `FuncValue` parameter.